# How to get customer id from Stripe in iOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments, strip

I have got STPToken, Card id from STPCard but I could not get the Customer id from STPCustomer in Stripe. Can any one please tell me how to get the customer Id(For eg: cus_asjdfhask234234ajsdf).

Comment: What do you mean by "_could not get the Customer id_" ? You don't know how to or the info you got is invalid somehow ?

Comment: i dont know how to..pls help

Comment: [STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken* token, NSError *error)
I used the above method and got the STPToken adn STPCard details but how to get the customer id ?

Comment: *  The Stripe ID of the customer, e.g. `cus_1234`
like this id..it is showing in STPCustomer class but i dont know how to get that id...pls help

Answer (score 0):

Customer ID's are generated on the server side. The app should collect the users credit card info and get a STPToken and then send that token to the server and the server will create you a Customer ID and send it back to the app then you can use that customer for making purchases which also happen on server side.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer

It is not possible to charge customers inside the app.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-you-charge-a-card-through-a-mobile-application

Comment: Thanks mate.. Helpful

Answer (score 0):

To generate customer id , we can also call stripe curl api at app side , as we call other rest apis.

You can refer Stripe's own document from below URL 
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer
Even one can do any stripe operation by Stripe's APIs.

You just need to pass customer id to your back end , as if you logout at app side & at login time you don't get old one customer id & you try to create new one by using same email then stripe will allow it & provide you new customer id.